# What team is good for the clash at bloodbath lagoon?

Tags: pit-people

My team is Horatio(big shield, mallet, big helm), Josef(net, small sword, med helm), Human(empty, small sword, med helm), troll mom.

With combination of fighters above, I managed to get to the last (assumption) step of fight where I need to beat the guy out of fishes mouth (I opened it once, hit the guy twice and then it closed), the problem is I simply die when the mouth opens as it hits you for ~15HP every time and you need to hit it open, I simply run out of HP...

[image]

I tried doing it with cupcakes instead of troll mom, but then I get hit too many times with tentacles crushing the end of the boat and end up overwhelmed due to lack of DPS.

**What team is good for the clash at bloodbath lagoon?**

Also, I am trying to rush, is it better to go slow(although I don't see how it could make it easier, still it's worth asking...)

Comment: To whoever is trying to close the question. There is nothing opinion based in this question, the game is ultra hard and to go past certain fights one needs to have a specific combination of fighters which can be not obvious to figure out on your own. I am trying to get myself unstuck with trying a different combination of fighters, but it's time-consuming, and I would appreciate the advice of those who have already done it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, two hair trolls seem to be the way to go + Horatio and Yosuf since they are required.

Additional tips: First part of the battle one needs to rush as much as he can as once the captain is defeated fight switches to the second part, so no need to kill all the trash mobs

[image]

However in second part once the boat is tipped over one needs to go as slow as he can so hairtrolls would get as much of lost health back as possible, and give priority to killing all the trash mobs especially squids, and not tentacles. Then later guys from the cars. Another thing worth mentioning, to open mouth only one hit is required, so use only one char instead of multiple and move them to mid ship. Then once he is out of the mouth give priority to killing 'parasite', since once he is dead the fight is over.